# Transforming the cartesian representation of a segment into polar form and viceversa

Tags: segment, cartesian

Suppose to have a segment described by its two extremes on cartesian plane, as two couples of coordinates.
I need to represent such segment in "polar form", as a couple *theta, d*, where *theta* is its slope and *d* its distance from origin of cartesian axes.

I guess I correctly computed *theta* as the slope of line containing segment.
On the other end, I have some doubts about *d*, because it seems to me that distance of origin from line containing segment is not exactly distance of segment from origin.
How would you compute the couple *theta, d*?

One more question: suppose to have a correct couple *theta, d*: do you think it's possible to get back to original cartesian representation and get back to original segment's extremes?

thanks for help.

Comment: This seems more of a mathematics question than a StackOverflow question unless you can show some associated code.

Comment: i must translate all this into code. that's all :)

Comment: This doesn't really make sense, as you can't convert a segment into polar form. You can, however, convert points (as in, the two endpoints of the segment) into polar form. In other words, in cartesian coordinates, you have a segment described by the endpoints `x1, y1` and `x2, y2`. Those same endpoints can be described in polar form by `r1, theta1` and `r2, theta2`. But the calculations between cartesian and polar coordinates are pretty simple, and a quick Google search would have found them in less time than it took to write up the question...

Comment: thanks for your answers. as you can see in my question, i used "" to surround the expression POLAR FORM, since it's not suitable for segments. anyway, i'm requested to use such representation for segments for my master thesis, so i don't need to convert its extremes in polar form (this would be easy). my question is: is there a way to denote the distance of a segment from origin? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the end points of an arbitrary segment are specified as (a,b) and (c,d) in Cartesian coordinates, then expressing that in polar form would simply be a matter of expressing the two endpoints in polar form (dist, angle).  In C, one might do that conversion like this:

```
double a,b;
dist = sqrt(pow(a,2)+pow(b,2));
angle = atan2(b, a);
```